# suppression of URLS in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I have a BibTeX format base of scientific citations. Almost all of them contain the field url=''. In a destinated document class (it was specially created and designed for handling PhDs according to a national standard) these entries yield bibliography with indicated URLs where this field is present in the bibtex base. How it is possible to suppress showing URLs without affecting the class package, by a command in a preamble or as an option to \bibliography command?

Comment: the bibliography style in my case is \bibliographystyle{gost2008}

Answer (score 4):

Given that you're using the `gost2008` bibliography style, I think you have two main options:

1. Create a modified version of the bibliography style that doesn't process the contents of `url` fields.

   - Find the file `gost2008.bst` in your TeX distribution; make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `gost2008nourl.bst`.
   - Open the file `gost2008nourl.bst` in a text editor (the editor you use for your tex files will do fine) and locate the function `format.url`. In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 1381. The function should look something like this:

     ```
     FUNCTION {format.url} 
     { url empty$
         { "" }
         {
           bbl.url ": \BibUrl{" * url * "}" *
           urldate empty$
             { "" }
             { " (" bbl.urldate * ": " * urldate * ")" * }
           if$ *
         }
       if$
     }
     ```
   - Replace the entire function with

     ```
     FUNCTION {format.url} 
     { url empty$
         { "" }
         { "" } 
       if$
     }
     ```

     I.e., replace the function with a "stub", effectively telling the bibliography style to "do nothing" whether or not the entry in question features a field called `url`.
   - Save the file `gost2008nourl.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as well.
   - In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{gost2008}` to `\bibliographystyle{gost2008nourl}`. Then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.
2. Alternatively, open the bib file in a text editor and replace all instances of `url =` and `url=` with `zzzurl=`.

   BibTeX ignores fields that aren't in the database of the bibliography style you use. While `gost2008` is programmed to something with fields called `url`, it (unsurprisingly) doesn't have instructions for what to do with fields called `zzzurl`.

   You will still need to re-run BibTeX and LaTeX after making the changing the field names from `url` to `zzzurl`.

Happy BibTeXing!